# Show second table on filter being applied to table one, else hide?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables. One of which is the latest entry for records in a table, and the other is the "master list" of entries with a record:

Table 1 example:

| Name | Date | YesNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 01/09/2021 | Yes |
| Test2 | 01/09/2021 | Yes |

Table 2 example:

| Name | Date | YesNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 01/09/2021 | Yes |
| Test2 | 01/09/2021 | Yes |
| Test1 | 31/08/2021 | Yes |
| Test2 | 31/08/2021 | Yes |
| Test1 | 30/08/2021 | Yes |
| Test2 | 30/08/2021 | Yes |

What I would like is Table 2 to be hidden on page, until the user clicks on a row in Table 1 (applying a filter to the sheet for that Name). So when the user clicks Test1 in Table 1 for example, Table 2 appears filtered to Test1 entries.

I have the filtering all set up fine, its just having Table 2 hidden by default, to then be shown when a row in Table 1 is selected. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by hiding the table with another widget like a text box.
Use the following measure to manage the visibility of the text box which should be placed on the top of the table that you want to hide;

```
BGCOLOR =  IF(ISFILTERED(Sheet1[Column2]),"#FFFFFF00","#FFFFFFFF")
```

Then use the background fx option to hide/show the text box;

[image]

[image]

You can also set some messages to the text box as well...

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. I have created the measure and applied it to a text box, but the box just becomes transparent no matter if there are filters applied or not?

Comment: The filtering is focused on columns, you may add all columns to the "if" condition...